# How to create a hexbin plot from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have this dataframe:

```
! curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msu-cmse-courses/cmse202-S21-student/master/data/Dataset.data

import pandas as pd

#I read it in
data = pd.read_csv("Dataset.data", delimiter=' ', header = None)

#Now I want to add column titles to the file so I add them
data.columns = ['sex','length','diameter','height','whole_weight','shucked_weight','viscera_weight','shell_weight','rings']
print(data)
```

Now I want to grab the x variable column `shell_weight` and the y variable column `rings` and graph them as a histogram using `plt.hexbin`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
plt.hexbin(x='shell_weight', y='rings')
```

For some reason when I graph the code it is not working:

> ValueError: First argument must be a sequence

Can anyone help me graph these 2 variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: First argument must be a sequence

The issue with `plt.hexbin(x='shell_weight', y='rings')` is that matplotlib doesn't know what `shell_weight` and `rings` are supposed to be. It doesn't know about `df` unless you specify it.

---

Since you already have a dataframe, it's simplest to plot with pandas, but pure matplotlib is still possible if you specify the source `df`:

- #### [`df.plot.hexbin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hexbin.html) (simplest)

  In this case, pandas will automatically infer the columns from `df`, so we *can* just pass the column names:

  ```py
  df.plot.hexbin(x='shell_weight', y='rings') # pandas infers the df source
  ```
- #### [`plt.hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html)

  With pure matplotlib, either pass the actual columns:

  ```py
  plt.hexbin(x=df.shell_weight, y=df.rings) # actual columns, not column names
  #            ^^^                ^^^
  ```

  Or pass the column names while specifying the `data` source:

  ```py
  plt.hexbin(x='shell_weight', y='rings', data=df) # column names with df source
  #                                       ^^^^^^^
  ```

  [image]